# Replace text with Javascript in any form it is written

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to find text in an html and highlight all occurrences of a text, replacing them for a span tag.

```
<div>This a sample paragraph. Sample is it?</div>
```

I am using the following piece of code to replace all occurrence of a word

```
var $test = $('div').html();

$test = $test.replace( new RegExp('sample',"g"), '<span class="hilite">sample</span>'
```

I would like to change all occurences of `sample` doesn't matter how it is written `[Sample, SAMPLE, samplE]` I would like to highlight the intended word, how could I do it?

Comment: Please don't edit the question.  Both existing answers are valid answers for the original question.  Anyone looking at your question *now* will see answers that don't match the question.  Are new answers more valid that the original answers?   How will you mark the *correct* answer? The first, correct answer, or a new one that doesn't answer the original question but now answers the edit?   Please create a new question (link to this one if desired).

Comment: Worse, the existing, correct answer now looks like it's just a copy of the code in your question and will likely elicit *downvotes*.

Comment: Restored the original question.

Comment: ok i got it, should i create a new question or edit this one with more details?

Comment: Yes, you can add more details for clarification (especially when questions are asked in the comments), as long as the overall question doesn't change - otherwise create a new question.

Comment: Did you tried [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$test = $test.replace(new RegExp('sample', "gi"), '<span class="hilite">sample</span>');
```

Use the `i` flag for insensitive.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: that was fast and painless, thanks

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the edit.  Seems I somehow deleted the search string.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Add the `toLowerCase()` function when you search for the word, like this:

```
var $test = $('div').html().toLowerCase();
```

[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: I like this suggestion as well. You can use the toLowerCase() which would make the need for RegEx unnecessary.  Not too sure how much faster computationally it would be. But it would be an interesting study.